# Error con mi array

Tags: array, c

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de mi universidad y no entiendo en donde estoy haciendo mal, lo hice igual al profe pero no entiendo por que me da error.

**Ejercicio:
Se deberá de desarrollar un programa que permita
ingresar las notas de N alumnos. El número de alumnos deberá ser ingresado.
Luego el programa deberá mostrar por pantalla el promedio general de todos los alumnos
que aprobaron (se aprueba con 6 o más). Mostrar cuántos alumnos aprobaron y cuántos reprobaron.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, i, ac=0;
    int nota; 
    float promedio;
    
    prinft("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: "); //error
    scanf("%d", &n); 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        do{
            printf("Ingrese la nota del alumno nro: %d", i);
            scanf("%d", &nota[i]);
        }while((nota[i]<0) || (nota[i]>10));
        ac = ac+nota[i];
    }
    promedio = (float)ac/cantidad;
    printf("\n El promedio es; %f",promedio);
}
```

Comment: Tu error es que estás declarando la variable `nota` como un entero y no como un arreglo de enteros. `int nota[n]`.

Comment: lo corregí, y no muestra el print para ingresar la cantidad de n alumnos (esta mal escrito el print, pero ya lo corregí)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 3 problemas:

- La función es `printf`, no `prinft`.
- La variable `int nota` no es un arreglo. `int nota[]` si es un arreglo. Nota que una tiene llaves y la otra no.
- No existe la variable `cantidad` en tu código. Quizá lo que quieras usar sea la variable `n`.

---

Me adelanto a lo que quizá estés pensando. Este código soluciona el problema pero genera otro:

```
int main(){
    int n, i, ac=0;
    int nota[n]; 
    float promedio;

    ...
}
```

En C los arreglos deben ser de tamaño constante. Por lo que al hacer eso el programa no debería compilar.

- Como el tamaño del arreglo no puede cambiar, una opción es hacerlo lo suficientemente grande. Ese será el máximo de elementos que puedas guardar en él. Por ejemplo, 100 elementos: `int nota[100]`.
- Una segunda solución consiste en no usar arreglos. No hay razón para guardar las notas individualmente, al menos para solo calcular el promedio. Un ejemplo de un caso que si lo requiere es si tienes que ordenar las notas.

  ```
  int main(){
      int n, i, ac = 0;
      int nota; 
      float promedio;

      printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ");
      scanf("%d", &n); 
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          do{
              printf("Ingrese la nota del alumno nro: %d", i);
              scanf("%d", &nota);
          } while((nota < 0) || (nota > 10));
          // Es lo mismo que ac = ac + nota
          ac += nota;
      }
      promedio = (float)ac / n;
      printf("\n El promedio es: %f", promedio);
  }
  ```
- Si aún necesitas las notas indivuales, en lugar de un arreglo tendrás que usar memoria dinámica.

  Para ello debes reservar memoria con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) pasándole el número de bytes a reservar. Para tener el espacio suficiente para 10 enteros llamarías a la función así:

  ```
  // sizeof devuelve el tamaño de un tipo en bytes
  int* numeros = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
  ```

  Para acceder a un elemento en particular puedes hacerlo como en un arreglo. Si quisieras hacer que el 5º elemento sea el número 12, lo harías así:

  ```
  numeros[4] = 12;
  ```

  Y al terminar de usarla debes liberarla pasando el puntero a la función [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

  ```
  free(numeros);
  ```

  El código te quedaría así:

  ```
  int main(){
      int n, i, ac = 0;
      int* notas;
      float promedio;

      printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      notas = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

      for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          do{
              printf("Ingrese la nota del alumno nro: %d", i);
              scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
          } while((notas[i] < 0) || (notas[i] > 10));

          ac += notas[i];
      }
      promedio = (float)ac / n;
      printf("\n El promedio es: %f", promedio);

      free(notas);
  }
  ```

  Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##dZDNTsMwEITvfopRUZHdFkiEkKB/Nw48A3BwbaddybGrJBUStM8eNn8tPbCXxLOrnW/H3G2NqesbCsYfrMOyrCzF@91aXEmeNo0mKFTINQWpfgS4mneYgWbQBiski0GdIMRKl90781FX2Bcxd7x8IVpxX/BYJkdvYVu40sFrGB0qstqCXbU/5CGWc4xUt6TkLo@P7WiG29CLrQkb59r7aGTABCV9u5hJXq5Ub5XFQlKLB8ISgT/TqWpb3RlN2Xj5/4evcWM238MhFBFjO/8IjEQ90VDXuA3mO33@mTnha0feSTn0GCxROB5xUdZIk/MRTXHI0xWGfrfs1KfZhctXyjZuxbMPfOpV1q/@Mug423HGdINyTqtwrmNg5VTXTyIVj@JZvIg0Eb8).